# how to measure low frequency(50Hz) with atmega32 more accurately

Tags: ac, atmega, frequency, frequency-measurement

I am trying to measure two AC source's frequency with atmega32, both will be around 50Hz. I already build the zerocrossing circuit using LM358, all I have to do with my atmega32 is to use the timer to read the square wave.until now i only manage to use the following simple method, which is to start the timer when the voltage on the pin is not zero, and stop the timer when the voltage reaches 0, then multiple the result with 2. I have to problems(questions) about this. 
first, it is not really accurate, but it is really sensitive.I always got 52Hz instead of 50, but it can sense up to 0.05Hz change. 
is there a better way to read the low frequency using atmega32?
second, I am having trouble reading to signals' frequency at a time. any suggestions?

```
int main(void)
{
  while(1)
{
   zerocrossingA(); 
   freA = frecalculationA();
   _delay_ms(20);
   zerocrossingB();
   freB = frecalculationB();
}

}
 void zerocrossingA(void)
{
  while(1)
{
      if ((PINA&(1<<7)) ==0 )
      {
            TCNT1=0;
            TCCR1B=0x01;
            break;
      }
      else
     {
            continue;
     }
}
while(1)
{
    if ((PINA&(1<<7)) !=0 )
    {
        TCCR1B=0x00;
        g1=TCNT1;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
}
 void zerocrossingB(void)
 {
    while(1)
 {
    if ((PINC&(1<<0)) ==0 )
    {
        TCNT1=0;
        TCCR1B=0x01;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    }
     while(1)
    {
       if ((PINC&(1<<0)) !=0 )
    {
        TCCR1B=0x00;
        g2=TCNT1;
        break;
     }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    }
    }

    double frecalculationA()
   {
     k1=1000000/(g1);
     w1=k1/2;
     return w1;
   }

   double frecalculationB()
   {
     k2=1000000/(g2+1);
     w2=k2/2;
     return w2;
   }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using Input Capture for this?

Comment: If your ZC hardware (which you should show us the circuit diagram of) is biased by a DC error offset away from true zero crossing point, then by looking at only a half cycle you will get a consistently wrong result. An easy way to check this is to invert your tests so as to measure the other half cycle. So eg if true frequency = 50 HZ and you see 50 Hz then: Total period = 1/50 = 20 mS. 52 Hz = 19.2 ms. Apparent 1/2 cycle = Whole cycle error = 9.62 ms. Other "half" will be 10.38 ms. Freq with inverted tests = 1/(2 x 10.38) =48.2 Hz. If inverting the tests give ~= 48 HZ look at ZC hardware.

Comment: Counting multiple cycles would be one way to reduce some errors (from zero crossing detection, from software delays of starting and stopping, for examples) by the factor of the number of cycles counted.

Comment: I did measure the other half, it still got the same result.

Comment: I am trying to read two or even more signals' frequency, atmega32 only have one input capture pin.......that's where limit my method.

Answer (score 1):

Read [AVR ref205](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8365.pdf) for synchronous counter/timer methods

[image]

- use derivative of 50 Hz square wave to detect edge to start count using either hardware or software with Irq to start a timer

> Example of dV/dt of Square wave is a 10kHz HPF into a current limited yet biased logic gate to get 1 pulse per cycle.   To make a ZCS pulse , delay path of square wave by T us then XOR with undelayed signal to get T us ZCS pulse at both transitions. This is twice the frequency.

- the ZCS edge detection may rely on software IRQ or some means to synch timer on edges.

However

- Resolution>=50/0.05=1000 counts or more per cycle, ie > 50kHz

### I suggest a higher frequency ref clock and measure full cycle due to most likely asymmetry error of your square wave.

- Thus one method is to AND the XOR output with the 50 Hz logic signal to get one narrow pulse per cycle for time interval counting method.
- Another is simply use either edge of clock to measure HF timer counts for resolution in 10us for example.

-verify accuracy and tune as required.

Comment: abbreviations? or format?

Comment: I didn't quiet understand your description. what do you mean by 'derivative of 50 Hz" .

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 better now with the edit; the start of line seemed to have converter a `>` into a "citation"